# I should want to publish post from by java web application (tomcat)

Tags: facebook, tomcat, facebook-java-api

I've created a facebook software that allow a web application (tomcat) to publish a post in my wall.
I used facebook-java-api-3.0.2 library and for make this operation FacebookJsonRestClient.stream_publish() method.
In the posts are present message, caption, link and photo.
When I make it I see all correctly, but my friends don't see it in my wall.
I should also want publish this post with Share button (now there isn't) and publish the post in the wall of my friends (now this doesn't happen).

Comment: What's your question?  Can you share some code to show how you're publishing the post?  Maybe contrast it with a working example?  Or any other relevant information about your Facebook integration?

Comment: Why don't you naming it as "posting content" and merge with your previous question? This is probably very same issue and not related to type of content you're trying to publish...

Comment: I made two question because I should want to structure my qquestion better.
The toher regards a specific problem I think to configure my app on Facebook; this one is relative to my java code.

Comment: This is my code (the app works offine_access):
FacebookJsonRestClient client = new FacebookJsonRestClient(myappcode, myappsecret);
try {
Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
String link = "http://www.stefanoerrani.it";
attachment.setHref(link);
attachment.setCaption("My Title");
attachment.setName("Stefano Errani");
AttachmentMediaImage attach_media = new AttachmentMediaImage("http://www.stefanoerrani.it/image2.jpg, link);
attachment.setMedia(attach_media);
client.stream_publish(desc, attachment, null, null, new Long(myFBUserId));
} catch (FacebookException ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}

Answer (score 0):

Rest API is being deprecated, I would highly suggest you build your solution using the latest APIs.  See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/